# Single select query to handle two conditions

Tags: mysql

I have a select query in which there is a where condition

```
  select column1,column2 from table1 where isnull(i.picturecolumn) != 1;
```

picturecolumn is in bytes data type.

I need to use hyperlink column , if hyperlink column is null, then look for picture column.

```
  select column1,column2 from table1 where isnull(i.hyperlinkcolumn) != 1;
```

ie:

```
if (hyperlink==null)
{
   select column1,column2 from table1 where isnull(i.picturecolumn) != 1;
}
else
{
select column1,column2 from table1 where isnull(i.hyperlinkcolumn) != 1;
}
```

I have single select query in the code, i need to replace with another select query to handle this, any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select column1,column2 
    from table1 
    where isnull(coalesce(i.hyperlinkcolumn, i.picturecolumn)) != 1;
```

Comment: "IS NOT NULL" -- COALESCE won't return 1.  No need to use ISNULL, COALESCE will return NULL if none of the columns return other than NULL.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I think I was typing my correction the same time you were typing your comment.

Comment: I don't get correct records, when i run with where isnull(i.picturecolumn) != 1 i get 200 records, where as when i run   where isnull(coalesce(i.hyperlinkcolumn, i.picturecolumn)) != 1; i get 1000 records.

Comment: @Shareye500: I would expect the second query to return more results than the first since it's now combining the check of both hyperlinkcolumn and picturecolumn. Can you clarify your expected results?

Comment: You should not combine both the column, if the hyper link is empty look for picture column, else check only with picture column.

Comment: @Joe - I think your query returns correctly, i will do few more testing & mark it as accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I think this is what you're looking for:
SELECT col1,col2 FROM table1 WHERE picturecolumn IS NOT NULL OR hyperlinkcolumn IS NOT NULL;

Basically, return results for anything where either one of those columns is not null.

Comment: Shouldn't be picturecolumn IS NOT NULL AND hyperlinkcolumn IS NOT NULL;

Comment: I may be wrong, but OR conditions throws wrong number of records.